# How to merge CSV and county shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, geoda, pysal

I have some data in a CSV file. One of the interested variable is test done (1=done, 2=not done). There is a variable of county name in which I would like to join with a county shapefile.

I only know how to join them using the county file as the base using ArcGIS, but the interested variable cannot be summarized correctly (as I would like each county to get a percent of 'done' from the interested variable).

How do I join it so I use the CSV as a base, such that I can get a percentage of 'done' later on?

Answer (score 1):

Your first step of joining on the county name is correct. From there it's not clear from your question exactly what percent you're looking for:

- each county's percent complete (count of done divided by total count
  of done and not done for each county)
- the percent for each county's done records out of all done records
  (count of done divided by total count of done for all counties)
- the percent for each county's done records out of all records (count
  of done divided by total number of records)

In any case you'll want to use the [Summary Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//00080000001z000000) tool with the county name and done/not done fields as CASE fields. The resulting table should have two rows for each county; one row will have a count of the done records for that county and the other the not done records. From there you can use field calculations to get whatever percentages you're looking for. You can also run a different Summary Statistics using only county name as a CASE field to get the total number of both done and not done per county.

Comment: I would like to have each count's percent, as in 'done' within each county divided by the sum count of 'done' and 'not done' in that county. Which software should this be computed? Does Arcgis have this function?

Comment: I think I need to restructure the csv data first by aggregating the data into unique county, and be able to compute a percent score for each county. I am looking at how to do it via SPSS, etc.

Comment: Yes, ArcGIS can do this by adding fields and using the Field Calculator. You are correct that it would be easiest done by rearranging your data first so that you have one row/record per county, with a column/field for done, one for not done, and then adding one for total and percentage. The easiest way in Arc to do this would be export done records to one table and not done records to another, then join them based on county name to get a 3 field table. Then add the other two fields in the attribute table window, right-click their headers, and use Calculate Field with the appropriate formula.